# Pyspark ipython notebook not printing

Tags: python, ipython, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

I have a pyspark data frame, whose single column I need to print on the ipython notebook

```
def f(e):
    print e.error
errors.foreach(f)
```

However, executing the above does not print anything, "error" is name of the column in the dataframe.

Same problem occurs when a function is called by worker threads but no output from the print commands is displayed in the notebook.

How to make it print , `sys.stdout.flush()` does not work either? Although only logging module which logs to a file works.

Comment: what does this have to do with spark ?

Comment: @eliasah I have encountered the same problem.  Calling print from within a spark method does not print anything on a jupyter notebook, but does from a regular ipython console.  Calling print outside of the spark context still works, so it is clearly a spark issue.

e.g. (in python3 so, print is a function):

    df.foreach(print)  

works in the console but not in the notebook.

Comment: @DaveKirby thanks for the clarification. I know how Spark work and I also know that if one read the first page of the documentation, he wouldn't ask this question.